# Error while not authenticate users try to see the content

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**DoesNotExist at /
Account matching query does not exist.**

I got error while the not authenticate user try to see the video
I need to let the not authenticate user can to see the content videos but absolutely can't to post any videos

The model

```
class Video(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
video = models.FileField(upload_to='post-videos')
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
allow_comments = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
publish_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The form

```
class Video_form(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Video
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'video')
```

The views

```
def home_screen_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
all_videos = Video.objects.all()
V_form = Video_form()
video_added = False
account = Account.objects.get(username=request.user)
if 'submit_v_form' in request.POST:
    print(request.POST)
    V_form = Video_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if V_form.is_valid():
        instance = V_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.author = account
        instance.save()
        V_form = Video_form()
        video_added = True

contex = {
    'all_videos': all_videos,
    'account': account,
    'V_form': V_form,
    'video_added': video_added
}
return render(request, "personal/home.html", contex)
```

The Html template

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<div class="container">

 <div class="mt-5">
  <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{V_form}}
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="submit_v_form">Upload</button>

  </form>
</div>

 {% endif %}
<hr>

    {% for x in all_videos %}
    <h3 class="text-center mt-2 mb-2">{{x.title}}</h3>
    <video class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" controls="controls" >
        <source src="{{x.video.url}}" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think my error in the views.py

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def home_screen_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    all_videos = Video.objects.all()
    V_form = Video_form()
    video_added = False
    
    if not request.user.is_active:
        # any error you want
        return HttpResponse('Inactive User')
    
    try:
        account = Account.objects.get(username=request.user)
    except:
        # any error you want
        return HttpResponse('User does not exits.')
    
    if 'submit_v_form' in request.POST:
        print(request.POST)
        V_form = Video_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if V_form.is_valid():
            instance = V_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = account
            instance.save()
            V_form = Video_form()
            video_added = True
    
    contex = {
        'all_videos': all_videos,
        'account': account,
        'V_form': V_form,
        'video_added': video_added
    }
return render(request, "personal/home.html", contex)
```

Comment: Thank you to answer my question the error disappear, but this wasn't I want, I want the not authenticate user can also see the videos and thank you for your time